# Add another column in the below query

Tags: sql

```
with test (tel) as  
(select '023158100001' from dual union all
    select '023158100002' from dual union all
  select '023158100003' from dual union all
  select '023158100004' from dual union all
  select '023158111545' from dual union all
  select '023158111546' from dual union all
  select '023158111547' from dual union all
    select '023158111617' from dual union all
 select '023158121110' from dual union all
    select '023158121111' from dual
    ),
    inter as
    (select tel,
     lag(tel) over (order by tel) lag_tel
     from test
    ),
   inter_2 as
   (select tel,
    sum(case when nvl(tel - lag_tel, 1) = 1 then 0 else 1 end) over 
   (order by tel) tel_group
   from inter
   )
   select min(tel) min_tel,
   max(tel) max_tel
   from inter_2
   group by tel_group
   order by 1;

MIN_TEL      MAX_TEL
------------ ------------
023158100001 023158100004
023158111545 023158111547
023158111617 023158111617
023158121110 023158121111
```

Now i want another column to be added in here Switch perhaps now 023158100001 023158100004 comes under one switch suppose S1 and 023158111545 to 023158111546 comes under S2 switch... now 023158111547 comes under S3 switch                 My output would be like

```
    MIN_TEL      MAX_TEL   Switch 
------------ ------------  ------------
023158100001 023158100004   S1                       
023158111545 023158111546   S2
023158111547 023158111547   S3
023158121110 023158121111   VS
```

Can any one tel me how to implement this logic using above query

Comment: Where/how is the switch information stored (or what is the general rule)? There's no reason you can't join another table to inter_2 and select columns from it.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...